# как с гитхаба скачать?

Tags: ubuntu, github

Программа flameshot, у нее баг. Как я понял здесь пофиксили https://github.com/flameshot-org/flameshot/pull/2369/files
как мне теперь ее установить?
Использую ubuntu, сори за тупой вопрос

Comment: Релиз v12.0.0 включает этот фикс — https://github.com/flameshot-org/flameshot/releases/tag/v12.0.0. Можете скачать внизу по ссылкам, если в репозитории вашего пакетного менеджера его ещё нет.

Comment: @tocic - но лучше все же брать https://github.com/flameshot-org/flameshot/releases/latest

Answer (score 1):

1. Pull Request в исходники для целей "как мне теперь ее установить" бесполезен чуть более, чем полностью
2. Этот PR уже смержен с основной базой, так что все релизы (которые и можно устанавливать) после даты слияния это исправление содержат

На вопрос "как установить" в комментарии уже правильно ответил @tocic